# How do I get the stack trace from an Exception Object in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, exception

How can I get the full stack trace from the Exception object itself?

Consider the following code as reduced example of the problem:

```
last_exception = None
try:
    raise Exception('foo failed')
except Exception as e:
    print "Exception Stack Trace %s" % e
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stack trace itself is not stored in the exception object itself. However, you can print the stack trace of the last recent exception using `sys.exc_info()` and the `traceback` module. Example:

```
import sys
import traceback

try:
    raise Exception('foo failed')
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_tb(*sys.exc_info())
```

If you do not want to display the stack trace immediately, it should be possible to store the return value of `sys.exc_info()` somewhere.

Comment: Storing the result of sys.exc_info() blindly would result in badness...  from http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info - "Warning Assigning the traceback return value to a local variable in a function that is handling an exception will cause a circular reference."

Comment: Also, instead of traceback.print_tb(*sys.exc_info()), I would recommend http://docs.python.org/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc to get a formatted traceback string.